# Dynamic variable with inside eval not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval

The two code snippets below should produce same output. But they aren't. It is not possible for me to test all edge cases and see if the `eval()` expression works or not. Can anyone please point out if the eval expression is correct or not?

PS: I now `evail()` is evil. I just don't see any other way to reduce the amount of code compared to the first snippet. My goal is to match any variable in the place of the `eval()` expression that ends with `Err`. Please do recommend any alternative to `eval()` in this situation if you have one.

```
          <button
            onClick={() => setCalledForSubmit(true)}
            disabled={
              calledForSubmit || !uname || unameErr || passErr || confPassErr
            }
            id="btn-submit"
            className="hvr-sweep-to-top"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
```

```
          <button
            onClick={() => setCalledForSubmit(true)}
            disabled={calledForSubmit || !uname || eval("/.*Err/")}
            id="btn-submit"
            className="hvr-sweep-to-top"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
```

Comment: just store all the Err in an `errors` array and check if it includes the value

Comment: I don't think that'll be possible as I want to show each `err` in different place which will require me to be able to identify each of them individually. And if I wanted to use objects, it would require me destructure the whole object to add something to it which would be very cumbersome because I'm using React and each `err` is part of the state. I'll have to change each of them individually.

Comment: The expression `eval("/.*Err/")` amounts to `"/.*Err/"`, nothing more. It doesn't magically match variables. Like Greedo says, use an array for this or change your approach. You don't have to determine whether the button is disabled or not inside the JSX. A general approach to validation is to set up an array of inputs with validations rules so you don't have to use individual variables at any point.

Comment: @KMABadshah you can have an object with the error name as key and that contains all the specificities of the error